# How can pass a parameter in script on 'OnClick' event in my asp page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to pass a parameter in my script sub, i try this on asp page :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinSoftWares" OnClick="ProductChange(product)"  runat="server" >Softwares</asp:LinkButton>
```

and this for script :

```js
    <script runat="server">
        Sub ProductChange(ByVal StrCommand As String)
            If StrCommand = "product" Then
                If Session("BlnProductShow") = 1 Then
                    Session("BlnProductShow") = 0
                Else
                    Session("BlnProductShow") = 1
                End If
                DoRefresh()
            End If

        End Sub

        Sub DoRefresh()
            If Session("BlnProductShow") = 1 Then
                DivProduct.Style.Value = "visibility: visible"
            Else
                DivProduct.Style.Value = "visibility: hidden"
            End If

        End Sub

    </script>
```

But i got this error :

'product' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You can try this: `OnClick="ProductChange('product')"`

Comment: I tried and i got this error : Expression expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience in `VB.Net` but in `C#` I would do in following way, add **`CommandArgument`** property and assign it with a default value and then in its on click I would get the value.

**Aspx:**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinSoftWares" 
                runat="server" 
                CommandArgument="Product" 
                OnClick="LinSoftWares_Click" > 
Softwares
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**C#**

```
protected void LinSoftWares_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkSender= (LinkButton)(sender);
    string value = lnkSender.CommandArgument;
    // do what you need here
}
```

**Edit:**

In case your argument "product" is dynamic then you can use `Eval("Product")` if your control is in some data binder control.

Comment: Welcome, pleasure helping you out.